# Can we write or call "C code" in XAML for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, c, windows-phone-8

Can we write or call "C code" in XAML for Windows Phone 8,

i'm having C library and i have to use it in WP8 application. any idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone doesn't support P/Invoke so, no. You can't. Especially if you want your app to be approved for the App Store:

> 4.2.2
>
> For Windows Phone OS 7.1  Apps that target Windows Phone OS 7.1 must
>   not invoke native code APIs by using PInvoke or COM interoperability.
>
> For Windows Phone 8  Apps that target Windows Phone 8 must not invoke
>   native code APIs other than the APIs listed at Win32 and COM API for
>   Windows Phone 8.

Remember, your C library is probably pre-compiled for x86 which means that you would have to re-compile the source for different devices.

Your best bet is to check out the C source and see how difficult it would be to port to C#.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can - but you have to link it against a C++ project. What you need is a WinRT component that links against that library and acts as a wrapper. That component can then be used in C#.

Check out [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh972425.aspx).

Comment: That link is for Windows Store Apps (which run on PCs and RT devices) rather than Windows Phone.